# Error when reading Google Maps hyperlink in the excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, hyperlink

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column called Map that has the link to the locations on Google Maps. I'm trying to get this link, but in the column on Pandas the text "Link" appears. Is it possible to get the spreadsheet URL using Pandas? Could someone help me, please!

[image]

Comment: AFAIK not possible with pandas. Hence the posted answer and linked thread both propose using openpyxl.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('filename.xlsm')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
hl = ws.cell(row=3, column=13).hyperlink
```